# Injecting custom repository in aspnetboilerblate

Tags: c#, castle-windsor, asp.net-core-2.0, aspnetboilerplate

I am trying to setup a customrepository becuase I have a full text search based query. But trying to setup a custom repository is throwing exception. Looks like I have not properly wired up dependency. Here is the code

```
    public interface ICustomRepository<TEntity, TPrimaryKey> : IRepository<TEntity, TPrimaryKey>
    where TEntity : class, IEntity<TPrimaryKey>
{
    IQueryable<TEntity> FromSql(string rawSqlQuery);
}

public interface ICustomRepository<TEntity> : ICustomRepository<TEntity,int>
    where TEntity : class, IEntity<int>
{

}


/// <summary>
/// Base class for custom repositories of the application.
/// </summary>
/// <typeparam name="TEntity">Entity type</typeparam>
/// <typeparam name="TPrimaryKey">Primary key type of the entity</typeparam>
public abstract class CustomRepositoryBase<TEntity, TPrimaryKey> : EfCoreRepositoryBase<CustomDbContext, TEntity, TPrimaryKey>, ICustomRepository<TEntity,TPrimaryKey>
    where TEntity : class, IEntity<TPrimaryKey>
{
    protected CustomRepositoryBase(IDbContextProvider<CustomDbContext> dbContextProvider)
        : base(dbContextProvider)
    {
    }

    // Add your common methods for all repositories

    public IQueryable<TEntity> FromSql(string rawSqlQuery)
    {
        var dbContext = GetDbContext();
        return dbContext.Set<TEntity>().FromSql(rawSqlQuery);
    }

}
```

And here is how I have done the di setup

```
IocManager.RegisterAssemblyByConvention(typeof(PropertySearchEntityFrameworkModule).GetAssembly());     
  IocManager.IocContainer.Register(Component.For(typeof(IPropertySearchRepository<,>))
                    .ImplementedBy(typeof(PropertySearchRepositoryBase<,>))
                    .LifeStyle.Transient);
```

But I am getting below exception

> System.MissingMethodException occurred   HResult=0x80131513
>   Message=Constructor on type
>   'Custom.EntityFrameworkCore.Repositories.CustomRepositoryBase`2[[Custom.CustomProperties.CustomProperty,
>   Custom.Core, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=null],[System.Int64, System.Private.CoreLib,
>   Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]]'
>   not found.   Source=
>   StackTrace:    at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceImpl(BindingFlags
>   bindingAttr, Binder binder, Object[] args, CultureInfo culture,
>   Object[] activationAttributes, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)

Not sure what I am missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CustomRepositoryBase` cannot be `abstract` and needs a `public` constructor:

```
public class CustomRepositoryBase<TEntity, TPrimaryKey> : EfCoreRepositoryBase<CustomDbContext, TEntity, TPrimaryKey>, ICustomRepository<TEntity,TPrimaryKey>
    where TEntity : class, IEntity<TPrimaryKey>
{
    public CustomRepositoryBase(IDbContextProvider<CustomDbContext> dbContextProvider)
        : base(dbContextProvider)
    {
    }

    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Implementation should be something like this.

```
public interface ICustomRepository : IRepository<Custom, int>
{

}

public class CustomRepository : CustomRepositoryBase<Custom, int>, ICustomRepository
{
public CustomRepository(IDbContextProvider<CustomDbContext> dbContextProvider,
        IObjectMapper objectMapper)
    : base(dbContextProvider, objectMapper)
    {
    }
}
```